# Modify choices labels in a Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to modify in my Twig template the labels of the choices that I have for a choice field in my form. I create my field as usual in PHP:

```
->add('registered','choice',array('choices' => array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'),'expanded' => true))
```

and then in my template if a condition is true then I want to do something like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.registered,{'choices':{'1':'Ναι','0':'Όχι'}})}}
```

So the idea would be that instead of Yes and No, I would get it in Greek. My problem is that I can't figure out the right attribute to pass to the form_widget function, I've tried with 'choices' but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put Yes and No in a global message [translation domain](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/documentation/translations.html) and Symfony will translate them automatically. In 2.1 you will be able to put translations for entities into different domains, not only into default one.